# prettyPhoto Jquery not loading

Tags: jquery, html, css, prettyphoto

I've gotten prettyPhoto to work before so I'm not sure exactly what is wrong. When I click on the image it just goes straight to youtube. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm currently at a standstill with it.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>My Name | Designer</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
            <meta name="viewport" comtemt="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
            <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
            <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <header>
              <a href="index.html" id="logo">
                <h1>My Name</h1>
                <h2>Designer</h2>
              </a>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
                   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div id="wrapper">
              <section>
                <ul id="gallery">
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hu6CIISutes" rel="prettyPhoto">
                      <img src="img/numbers-01.jpg" alt="">
                      <p>Logo Animation</p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </section>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
          });
        </script>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What behavior do you want? Were you trying to make the video play in the lightbox?

Comment: Yes I am, currently it just goes to youtube when clicked